# Ubuntu SFTP connection to Ubuntu server rejecting with "Permission denied, please try again."

Tags: permissions, openssh, sftp, pam

I have a personal server connected to my local network,
and recently wanted to set up an SFTP-Server on it for some media transfer.
When I try to connect to it however, it asks for my password, but even the correct one gives an error stating "Permission denied, please try again."

I have a main SSH account for server management, which works fine using public key authentication.

The other user called `sftp-default` is in group `sftp`.
I set a password for `sftp-default` using `# passwd sftp-default`

Here is my /etc/ssh/sshd_config (Commented sections left out):

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
Port 468

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

UsePAM yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive

X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Match User sftp-default
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        AuthenticationMethods password,publickey
        ChrootDirectory /mnt/raid/mediaServers/sftp
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

The /mnt/raid/mediaServers/sftp has the following permissions using `stat`:

```
  File: /mnt/raid/mediaServers/sftp
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 821h/2081d      Inode: 3014657     Links: 4
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1004/sftp-default)   Gid: ( 1004/    sftp)
Access: 2023-01-02 15:41:30.271437209 +0100
Modify: 2022-09-04 17:14:16.724283747 +0200
Change: 2023-01-02 15:41:30.287436770 +0100
 Birth: 2022-09-04 16:12:38.458449835 +0200
```

Now when I try to do `sftp -P 468 sftp-default@<local_ip>` it gives my the following output when I try to enter the password 3 times.:

```
sftp-default@<local_ip>'s password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
sftp-default@<local_ip>'s password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
sftp-default@<local_ip>'s password: 
sftp-default@<local_ip>: Permission denied (password).
Connection closed.  
Connection closed
```

Note: `<local_ip>` is the local IP address

Connections via SSH reject in the same way.
Running `ssh sftp-default@<local_ip> -p 468 -v`, it outputs:

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <local_ip> [<local_ip>] port 468.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <local_ip>:468 as 'sftp-default'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/%user%/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:WK/sXtplQBRUA/guEF9HF6XiMZORiXdPVwweF5m467Q
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/%user%/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[<local_ip>]:468' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/theophil/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
sftp-default@<local_ip>'s password: 

[2 more authentication tries]

debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
sftp-default@<local_ip>: Permission denied (password).
```

Note: I had to take some parts out for the spam filter.
Local IP-Address replaced with `<local_ip>`,
the username that tries to connect to the server is replaced with `%user%` and
some SHA-Checksums are replaced with `[Checksum hidden]`.

Anything obvious, I am missing?
I couldn't find much on the web stating a solution for this exact problem.

I also don't really know, what this `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` means, but commenting it out and restarting the SSH daemon also did nothing to the problem.

I already have port 468 open on UFW. Does SFTP use another port for data transfer?
Also tried 777 (drwxrwxrwx) permissions on `/mnt/raid/mediaServers/sftp` with both `root` and `sftp-default` user using `# chown sftp-default:sftp -R /mnt/raid/mediaServers/sftp` and `# chmod 777 -R /mnt/raid/mediaServers/sftp`

Comment: Check the syslogs to see if the ssh server process is logging a reason why you're failing to authenticate.

Comment: The `/var/log/auth.log` now contains a lot of debugging info after setting `LogLevel DEBUG3` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but what eventually comes out is: `sshd[1812]: debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for sftp-default: Permission denied`. Maybe PAM does have something to do with this, since I have enabled it for 2FA in my main account.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer regarding the Google Authenticator PAM module, I had set up for 2FA on my main SSH account.
Somehow, it blocked access to all accounts, that hadn't set it up, meaning my `sftp-default` account was also blocked out.
The fix for me was to disable the Google Authenticator PAM module for group `sftp`, which I did with the following line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
#Disable SSH PAM authentication for SFTP-Users
auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup sftp
```

Now everything works fine and I can log in with my `sftp-default` account:

```
sftp-default@<local_ip>'s password: 
Connected to <local_ip>.
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /mnt/raid/mediaServers/sftp
sftp> bye
```